# Can we use Markdown with Bot Framework for Skype for Business?

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

Can we use Markdown with Bot Framework for Skype for Business?

We implemented a code to send an image following the document below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-create-messages

But it didn’t work. So we though Skype for Business may not be able to use Markdown feature.

Comment: [_"Skype for Business plans to roll out support for formatted messages around mid-to-late June"_](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2874)

Answer (score 0):

Markdown is not currently a supported text format for Bot Framework bots on the Skype for Business channel.

For more information on supported message formats see: [Skype for Business Bot Framework (Preview) > Feature Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#feature-support)

> Messages : Your bot can send plain text, HTML, and emoticons to a user or group. Users can send rich text, HTML, and emoticons to your bot.

Note: HTML support is [planned for mid-to-late June release.](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2874)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the situation is very clear for us.