# How to render markdown with Microsoft Bot Framework in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, botframework, chatbot, skype-for-business

I am facing an issue with rendering markdown text.
It does not show up in Skype For Business. Nothing is received, but if I don't write the setTextFormat code line, I receive a plain string.

```
Activity reply = activity.createReply("**This is a bold string**");
reply.setTextFormat(TextFormatTypes.MARKDOWN);
this.connector.getConversations()
                .sendToConversation(
                        activity.getConversation().getId(),
                        reply);
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks.

EDIT : Same issue with XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Skype for Business bots are deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness) in case you were unaware:

[image: Important notice]

> #### Important
>
> **Skype for Business channel in Bot Framework is being deprecated on June 30, 2019.**
>
> No new bots will be able to add Skype for Business channel after that
>   date. Existing bots will continue to work until October 31, 2019.
>   Microsoft Teams is the preferred communication tool from Microsoft.
>   [Learn how to connect your bot to Microsoft Teams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft-teams/bots).

Because it's impossible for me to test your issue there is no way for me to know if Markdown was ever supposed to be supported in Skype for Business, though you may be interested in reading this: [Can we use Markdown with Bot Framework for Skype for Business?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431060/can-we-use-markdown-with-bot-framework-for-skype-for-business). There may have been some way to format messages, but even if there was you should be using a different channel anyway. Even if you weren't making bots, [you have less than two years left with Skype for Business](https://www.onmsft.com/news/microsoft-announces-end-of-life-date-for-skype-for-business-online-july-2021) and it's recommended that everyone move to Teams.

If you have any more questions about the Bot Framework then please make a new post and my team will be happy to answer you.